# Rxjava how to generify transformers?

Tags: rx-java2, reactivex

I've found myself writing a lot of transformers to generify some stream operations such as retry, apply schedulers, etc. Which made me write a lot of code duplication because each stream type(single, completable, etc.) has it's own Transformer so I had to implement 4 different transformers which do exactly the same. That's also led to duplication in tests. Is there a way to generify transformers?

Comment: You can't. The reactive base types are distinct in the type system and thus you can't create a single transformer that can work with all of them through a single method.

Comment: do you have any suggestion to avoid my problem? maybe I missuses the reactive types?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5654) is a chain of discussions which lead to the `as` operator as the means to be able to implement all transformers within one class, but you still have to write the code multiple times.